# Where do I have to import a page on Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I don't very understand, when I create a simple page with Ionic 3 with the following command `ionic g page contact`, where exactly have I to link the files and the page?

Only on src/app/app.module.ts with this line?

```
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
```

Why do I need to push it on `providers` and `declarations` then? I have to do this for all the page my app will have?

And if I want create a link to this page, I have to import it too on the homepage's typescript file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

when you create a page using

`ionic g page testpage`

first we need to import it in `app.module.ts` file

```
import { TestpagePage } from '../pages/testpage/testpage';
```

and in  `declarations` array and `entryComponents` array

```
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    TestpagePage
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    TestpagePage
  ],
```

We no need to push it into `providers` array. and for example, if you want to navigate to this page from homepage, then

-> import testpage in `home.ts` file

`import { TestpagePage } from '../testpage/testpage';`

and on button click event,

`this.navCtrl.push(TestpagePage);`

**declarations** :
In the declarations section we need to include all components and directives we create.If we don't include them here, we'll get an error when we try to use them  because Angular won't be able to recognise them in our code.

**entryComponents**:
In the entryComponents section we define any component that is only loaded by its type. This is the case for all Page components since these are all 
loaded through the Navigation Controller.

Components that are loaded declaratively (i.e. are referenced in another component's template) don't need to be included in the entryComponents array.
So as you can see we have some duplication where we have to define our Page components in both the declarations and the entryComponents sections.
The reason for having this separate entryComponents section is so that Angular can compile a bundle for the app that will only include the components 
that are actually used within the app.

**providers**:
In the providers section we can register services for dependency injection. When you register a service in the App Module, it can be used in all the
components in your app.
However, we don't need to include all our services here, we can also decide to register a service only for a specific component in its `@Component` 
decorator.

source: [check this URL](https://gonehybrid.com/exploring-app-module-and-app-component-in-an-ionic-2-app/)

Comment: Thanks
And about the tab, I don't understand why it's a page, when I want add tabs to my app, I have to type "ionic g page tabs", but it's a specific page?

Comment: And so, I not have to import all my pages on app.components.ts? Only in app.module.ts?

Comment: Ionic g page tabs...will create a page named tabs in the project..it will not create tabs structure

Comment: Ok thanks. If I understand, all the pages, components, and provider using in the APP have to be import in the app.module? It's normal do have many imports in this file, right?

Comment: Yes.. you can have as many imports as required.. there is no limit

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to import a page to `app.module.ts` every time we create a page, that's anti `DRY`, boring and `app.module.ts` becomes fat

With the new ionic cli, we can generate a page like as:

```
ionic generate page pagename
```

This will generate the page as well as the corresponding module `pagename.module.ts` . Then you can refer it from any other page by name in `STRING`. For e.g.:

```
this.navCtrl.push("pagename");
```